# Can someone please tell me where I went wrong?

Tags: javascript

Question: Very Odd

Write a function, veryOdd. The function accepts an array of numbers. It should return a new array that contains only the odd numbers from the given array. veryOdd must not mutate the given array.

**My Code**

```
function veryOdd(array) {
  let newArray = array.slice();
  for (let i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
    let number = newArray[i];
    if (number % 2 === 1) {
      newArray.push(number);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

Comment: `let newArray = array.slice();` <-- so you make a copy of the array and proceed to push to the end of this.... Do you see your problem now? Declare a new array, loop over the original array.

Comment: @Nonik that has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) creates a copy and seems to be what's needed. `array.filter(num => num % 2 === 1)`

Comment: In the future, it would be helpful to post some sample output from the program. Do you get an error message? Does the code return incorrect results? It's hard to tell without each of us running the code ourselves. Save the world some time by posting your output :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you are pushing on to the end of the array you are iterating over, and the loop will never finish.

But there is a much simpler solution: [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The filter() method *creates a new array* with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
function veryOdd(a) {
  return a.filter(x => x % 2 !== 0)
}
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const y = veryOdd(x);
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how it would return the expected output.

```js
let array = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
  array.push(i);
}


function veryOdd(array) {
  let newArray = []; // create a new array to push the required elements to
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // use the param array 
    let number = array[i]; // use the param array
    if (number % 2 === 1) {
      newArray.push(number); // Add the required elements to the new array
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(veryOdd(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you want:

- Assign a new (empty) array to 'newArray'
- Assign the current element from the source 'array'
- Change the modulus result check to be Not-0

```js
function veryOdd(array) {

  let newArray = [ ];

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i ++) {

    let number = array[i];

    if ((number % 2) !== 0) {
      newArray.push(number);
    }
  }

  return newArray;
}

let res = veryOdd([ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]);

console.log(res.length);

console.log(res);
```